# how to pass directory as arguments to python script using shell command?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to pass two directories to my python script which just prints out the directory. But somehow its not working. Below is the code

**shellscript.sh:**

```
set VAR1=$(pwd)
echo $VAR1
set VAR2=$(pwd)
echo VAR2
python.exe mypython_script.py "$VAR1" "$VAR2"
```

**mypython_script.py:**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ = '__main__':
    print(sys.argv[1])
    print(sys.argv[2])
```

The `echo` is printing the path, but the terminal also does print the script call line. There its showing `python.exe mypython_script.py '' ''` and then print statements are printing empty string. Could anyone point out to me where the problem is? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you should call python.exe instead of only python?

Comment: @LukasIsselbächer Yea. the script is running but printing empty string

Comment: Remove the `set` command. So you should have `VAR1=$(pwd)`.

Comment: I got it working by using just `python` no `.exe` and then getting rid of `set` as was suggested, so just make it `python` and then no `set` and it should run fine.

Comment: bash for windows maybe?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule. yes this script runs in VM which has windows OS as jenkins job and there cygwin is used to run the shell file.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with

```
set VAR1=$(pwd)
```

You should use

```
VAR1=$(pwd)
```

instead.

Comment: You also don't need to run `pwd`; `bash` already has a shell parameter `PWD` that expands to the name of the current working directory. Setting `VAR1` is redundant.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you all for your valuable inputs. As mentioned in the answer section, after removing SET identifier the script is working fine. :)

Comment: Additionally i would like to know that is there a possibility that i can stop the terminal from displaying the arguments for the script. Because the path is very long and it is not necessary.

Comment: Isn't the terminal displaying the path because of  the `echo` commands? Remove those to stop displaying them?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that in `bash`, `set` is used to **set and unset values of shell options and positional parameters** (not for assigning values to variables).

Comment: @JonDeaton Yes the echo is on but i would only like to not display the arguments for the script.